# How do I enable Clean URLs on Zend Server CE?

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd.conf, zend-server-ce

I installed Zend Server CE followed by Drupal. I would like to enable clean urls for the local site but I am not able. How do I do that?

Also, any changes being made to the httpd.conf file are not taking effect after I restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

The `AllowOverride` had to be set to `All` from the original value from `None` for the htdocs directory of my server.

The permissions for httpd.conf file were not set correctly. The user had no editing rights. After setting those, the changes were taking effect.